# How can i get invisible URL from website?

Tags: url, publish, invisible

Some URls and Some of images are uploaded on server and is visible on specific time.

How can i get that URLs /Images before visible/server publish on specific time.

Comment: Can you make me the question little bit clear ?

Comment: Ok an image uploaded on server but this image visible on a specific time. for e.g. 4:00 PM. with url like www.xyz.com/images/abcd.jpg. Now i want this url before 4:00 PM.but be clear abcd.jpg is encoded and i dont want to decode the string and get url..is that any method or tool from where i can get URL/Images before visible on site ?

Comment: where that image timing is stored? What you are trying to say encode mean ?

Comment: I only know that the images uploaded on server at 1:00 to 3:00 PM but visible at 4:00 PM daily .when i click on image i redirect to other page with some url parameter id which is encoded.Like www.xyz.com/MUser/action.aspx?ID=%2fxYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ%3d%3d. so how can i get this url/images before visible on web-site ?

Comment: How www.xyz.com/MUser/action.aspx?ID=%2fxYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ%3d%3d. this url is generated?

Comment: So want to generate that kind of url for the image given in that location,am i right?

Comment: no it is allready generated but i got on 4:00 pm when server publish..i want to this URL before server publish

Comment: any method /tools which are give us the all url of website ?

Comment: check out this http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Comment: it will return only those URl which is visible on site...what about inviisble link / backlink ?